# trying to identify a pivot high using input.time in pinescript

Tags: label, pivot, pine-script

This is a follow up question to: [trying to identify one bar to the left and one bar to right of a selected bar using input.time in pinescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75079222/trying-to-identify-one-bar-to-the-left-and-one-bar-to-right-of-a-selected-bar-us)

Trying to write a script that will identify if a selected bar using input.time is a pivot high. the code below doesnt seem to work (the label always displaye "Not True". Would appreciate any assistance:

```
start_time = input.time(timestamp("20 Jan 2021"), "Start Calculationr", confirm=true)
displayStdDev = input.bool(false, title = "Display Std Dev Bands")
mult = input(2, title = "Standard Deviation Bands")

var int barStart = 0
if time == start_time
    barStart := bar_index

if barStart

    var isPivotHigh = barStart == ta.pivothigh (1,1) // determine if the selected bar is a pivot
    var ph = isPivotHigh ? "true" : "not true"
    var l1 = label.new(x=barStart, y=high, text=ph, color=color.white)
```

Expecting the code to print "True" when the selected bar = pivot high and "false" when not. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xgx6Z.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ta.pivothigh doesn't return true or false but the value of the pivothigh if exist or Nan.
And you must be aware that pivothigh is a lagging indicator : You have to select a bar, and you will know in the bar before if this bar is a pivothigh (if you are using ta.pivothigh(1,1) ... if you choose to use ta.pivothigh(10,10) there is a 10 bars lag).

You should try this :

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)

start_time = input.time(timestamp("2 Jan 2023"), "Start Calculationr", confirm=true)

PivotValue = ta.pivothigh(high, 1, 1)
isPivotHigh =  PivotValue == high[1]


if time == start_time
    ph = isPivotHigh ? "true" : "not true"
    l1 = label.new(x=bar_index-1, y=high[1], text=ph, color=color.white)
```

This code is tested and give this type of result :

[image]

Comment: Thank you! But i only need it to show if the selected bar is a pivot high or not - not all bars..

Comment: @AJ79 yes I know, it was for the example. If you only want the selected bar, use if time == start_time. Please accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: Hi mate - no i get an error f i use time == start_time : "Pine cannot determine the referencing length of a series...".. i added max_bars_back =5000 but get the same error. First it shows  a whole bunch of "true" and "not true" labels stacked on top of each other way below the selected bar, then after a little while it spits out the max bars error.

Comment: The goal is just to determine if the selected bar is a pivot high .... adding the label to test that the code is working correctly ..

Comment: @AJ79 I update my answer, hope it will help you.

Comment: thank you this was very helpful. I made one minor adjustment to it so that it will display if the selected bar is a pivot high. "if time[1] == start time" does the trick. : Final code: 

//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)

start_time = input.time(timestamp("2 Jan 2023"), "Start Calculationr", confirm=true)

PivotValue = ta.pivothigh(high, 1, 1)
isPivotHigh =  PivotValue == high[1]


if time[1] == start_time
    ph = isPivotHigh ? "true" : "not true"
    l1 = label.new(x=bar_index-1, y=high[1], text=ph, color=color.white)